# Postgres Large Objects & Multiple Users

Tags: postgresql, users

## Problem

Dynamically created users are not able to query a table that contains **Large Objects** as it did not originally create it.

---

### Background

I have an Java Atom Hopper application deployed to AWS across **2 instances**, both using a **Postgres 9.5.2** database hosted in RDS.

### Vault Credentials

The database credentials are stored in [Vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vault.html), which generates a new login and password for the databases in Postgres. This user is created with the following permissions.

```
CREATE ROLE "{{name}}" WITH INHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on DATABASE "DATABASE_NAME" to "{{name}}";GRANT databaserole to "{{name}}";
```

This means each time the Java application starts, it sends a request to **Vault**, to get a new username and password.

```
eg. username: token-1234-5678
=> \du

       Role name     |                  Attributes                   |   Member of
    -----------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------
    token-1234-5678  |  Password valid until 2016-09-11 09:57:14+00  | {databaserole} (java instance 1)
    token-abcd-efgh  |  Password valid until 2016-09-11 09:57:14+00  | {databaserole} (java instance 2)
```

The tables inside of the database are all owned by `databaserole`

```
Schema |          Name           | Type  |     Owner
-------+-------------------------+-------+----------------
public | table1                  | table | databaserole
public | table2                  | table | databaserole
public | entries                 | table | databaserole
```

### Inserting Data

When I insert a new row into table entries, one of the fields is too large and therefore converted into a **Large Object**, but its owner is set to the login of the app that inserted it, rather than `database role`.

```
=> \lo_list
            Large objects
  ID   |     Owner       | Description
-------+-----------------+-------------
 17286 | token-1234-5678 |
```

As the Java application on instance 2, has a different login to instance 1 eg. `token-abcd-efgh`, it means it cant execute `select * from entries;` as it is not the owner of the **Large Object**.

I am aware that I can change the owner of the object after it has been created, but this is not feasible due to the number of insertions.

---

## Question

How can I set it so that any **Large Object** has the owner of `databaserole` rather than the login of the application that created it?

---

### **TLDR**

As I have an multiple instances of an app, with unique and dynamically created logins. How can I setup Postgres so that the **Large Objects** always have the ownership of the role's member parent, so that any login that is a member of this parent role can view the object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-role.html) command after you open a connection from your application to the `databaserole`:

```
SET ROLE databaserole;
```

In such way any object (including large objects) created within this session will be owned by `databaserole` instead of `token-XXX`.

Another option is to use `LOCAL` and make it work only within the transaction used to create the large object:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL ROLE databaserole;
-- create and insert the large object
COMMIT;
```

Alternatively, you could just set the role directly as the user setting:

```
ALTER ROLE "{{name}}" SET role TO 'databaserole';
```

I kind of dislike that option as it can become a bit obscure to others how it is working, and if you manage other roles to your user it won't inherit them (although that doesn't seem like a problem to you, as with dynamically created user you should have a single role that it directs inherit from).

Comment: This doesn't work e.g. when `databaserole` is read-only, and the user gets their write permissions from elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I setup Postgres so that the Large Objects always have the
>   ownership of the role's member parent

There's no way to do that. But if you have control over the program's code, it could issue

```
GRANT SELECT ON LARGE OBJECT :objid TO databaserole;
```

immediately after each object is created.

---

Otherwise, a drastic solution would be switching the database to pre-9.0 large object permissions:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET lo_compat_privileges TO on;
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-LO-COMPAT-PRIVILEGES):

> **lo_compat_privileges** (boolean)
>
> In PostgreSQL releases prior to 9.0, large objects did not have access privileges and were, therefore, always readable and writable by
>   all users. Setting this variable to on disables the new privilege
>   checks, for compatibility with prior releases. The default is off.
>   Only superusers can change this setting.
>
> Setting this variable does not disable all security checks related to large objects — only those for which the default behavior has
>   changed in PostgreSQL 9.0. For example, lo_import() and lo_export()
>   need superuser privileges regardless of this setting.

This might make sense because the logic of "extending rows" by large objects is at odds with the post-9.0 large object permissions logic.
The difference is that future rows in a table have access rights predetermined by GRANTS to the table, whereas the concept of access rights applying to not-yet-created large objects does not exist.

Lastly, if there is a way to reconfigure your application so that it uses `bytea` fields instead of large objects, that would be an ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I can get it working using the GRANT manually, but I can only do that after the large object has been created. ideally I want a rule for all future large objects.

Also my plan was to try lo_compat_privileges, but it appears that RDS completely restricts changing it to anything other than off.

Answer (score 0):

One final option is to [change the owner](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterlargeobject.html) after creating the object.

```sql
ALTER LARGE OBJECT :objid OWNER TO databaserole;
```

You can also use a trigger to do this.